# wrong parameter returning to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running on Lavarel and crossing this code:

```
{{ link_to_route('users.edit', 'Edit', array($user->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
```

This is the `./app/views/users/edit.blade.php`

```
@extends('users.scaffold')

@section('main')

<h1>Edit User</h1>
{{ Form::model($user, array('method' => 'patch', 'route' => array('users.update', $user->id))) }}
<ul>
    <li>
      {{ Form::label('username', 'Username: ') }}
      {{ Form::text('username') }}
    </li>
    <li>
      {{ Form::label('password', 'Password: ') }}
      {{ Form::text('password') }}
    </li>
    <li>
      {{ Form::label('email', 'Email: ') }}
      {{ Form::text('email') }}
    </li>
    <li>
      {{ Form::label('phone', 'Phone: ') }}
      {{ Form::text('phone') }}
    </li>
    <li>
      {{ Form::label('name', 'Name: ') }}
      {{ Form::text('name') }}
    </li>
    <li>
      {{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
      {{ link_to_route('users.show', 'Cancel', $user->id, array('class' => 'btn')) }}
    </li>
</ul>
{{ Form::close() }}

@if (($errors->any()))
  <ul>
    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
  </ul>
@endif

@stop
```

The above code in the template file `edit.blade.php`, and when users click to the `Edit` button, it should pass the user id `$user->id` to the controller `UsersController@edit` where edit action is defined,

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    if(is_null($user)) {
        return 'Not found: '.$id;
        // return Redirect::route('users.index');
    }

    return Redirect::route('users.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

The problem here is that `$id` is not what passing from `link_to_route()` function. 
Can anyone help me find out where the problem is? Thanks.

Here the DOM result:

```
<a href="http://laravel.learn/users/1/edit" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
```

This is the `routes.php`

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

This is result after clicking Edit button:

```
Not found: {"id":1,"username":"john","password":"johndoe","email":"johndoe@gmail.com","phone":"123456","name":"John","created_at":"2013-06-07 08:13:28","updated_at":"2013-06-07 08:13:28"}
```

Comment: How does your routes.php for this specific code look?

Comment: Can you inspect the DOM that produces the button and put the compiled HTML in your question?

Comment: I've just updated the question for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your info - it looks like the problem is not with `link_to_route()` - you can see the error is further in your code.

It looks like you have bound the route to the model, so in your edit function `$id` is actually the `$user` already populated from the database.

You can tell that is the case - because your custom "not found" error gives you the user data.

If you change your code to this - does it work?

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    return Redirect::route('users.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: I've change like yours above, and got error `This webpage has a redirect loop` , with url is `http://localhost/users/1/edit`. I've updated the post with the view `/app/views/users/edit.blade.php`